# Automatically Collapse Accordian Style Tab After Clicking + Icon with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've implemented an accordian tab style layout on my Shopify site using the following CSS code:

```css
.so-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.so-tab label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.so-tab input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}


/* :checked */

.so-tab input:checked~.so-tab-content {
  max-height: none;
}


/* Icon */

.so-tab label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="radio" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">FEATURES</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="radio" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">DESCRIPTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-3" type="radio" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-3">SPECS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-4" type="radio" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-4">DETAILS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

It works perfectly except that in order to collapse an open tab it is necessary to click the + icon of a different tab. It is not possible to collapse an open tab simply by clicking the + icon again after the tab is already open. I would like to implement this functionality in my code. Keep in mind, I also want to preserve the current functionality of only having one tab open at a time (so if a user clicks FEATURES tab and then DESCRIPTION, the FEATURES tab must automatically close)

Please note I am looking for a purely CSS solution (if it is impossible to accomplish this with CSS alone I would accept something with JS but it is not ideal)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use checkboxes instead of radio inputs.

```js
// Uncheck others
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".so-accordion-wrapper input[type=checkbox]");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var others = document.querySelectorAll(".so-accordion-wrapper input[type=checkbox]:not(#" + e.target.id + ")");
    for (var j = 0; j < others.length; j++) {
      others[j].checked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.so-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.so-tab label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.so-tab input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.so-tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}


/* :checked */

.so-tab input:checked~.so-tab-content {
  max-height: none;
}


/* Icon */

.so-tab label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-1" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-1">FEATURES</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-2" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-2">DESCRIPTION</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-3" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-3">SPECS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="so-tab"><input id="so-tab-4" type="checkbox" name="tabs"> <label for="so-tab-4">DETAILS</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the functionality I am seeking. However, as I mentioned in the OP, I need that when one expands FEATURES for example and then expands DESCRIPTION the FEATURES section must collapse automatically . In other words, only one section should be open at any given time. If I use radio buttons I get this functionality. If I use check boxes I get the functionality you describe. The problem is I need both. Thanks!

Comment: Right, see updated snippet. It cannot be done without JS. JS is pretty simple though.